# Android: NullPointerException on webview

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception, webkit

Does anyone have this problem? I am not quite understand how to fix it. Not sure is that my code cause this exception or a bug on a webview.

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setNewText(WebViewClassic.java:587)
>   at
>   android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setComposingText(WebViewClassic.java:327)
>   at
>   android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.commitText(WebViewClassic.java:343)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Do you have any more to this stack trace?

Comment: That is all i have. I got it from the android developer console in Crash Report section. I can't duplicate on my device. Therefore i can't really give any more details about this exception

Comment: can you step through the code just to see where this hits.. seems like an internal bug but no one is reporting this.

Comment: To be honest, this is the first time being reported. I can step through the code but may take a long long time since i don't know which part of the code i should start from

Comment: heheh yeah i hear you man.  Is it possible to step through the activity that calls this webView? I'm not entirely familiar with webView but if there are ANY kind of parameters that you pass into webview I would start there.

Comment: Same issue here... can't be sure what causes it but it appears in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Hi That's an BUG in the AdMob's new GooglePlayServices Library integrated to our latest updates.

I got this from an admob SDK team member from [Amy Quispe(AdMob SDK Team)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/QvUhH5ZGIHQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setNewText(WebViewClassic.java:587)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setComposingText(WebViewClassic.java:327)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
```

I got the same error yesterday, I think it is generated from lib of new `google-play-services.jar`.

If you observe the snippet, `admob` update is mandatory to mitigate the issue.

Comment: How do I update the admob? Can you please elaborate?