# Java nullpointer exception from Webview

Tags: android, adview

I tried to search for this problem but this error doesn't look to be the same as [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866459/android-nullpointerexception-on-webview) (my google play version is newer and notice that the error is at a different line of WebViewClassic, so might be different error or the same in a newer version) but I have received the exactly same error exception from webview

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setNewText(WebViewClassic.java:583)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setComposingText(WebViewClassic.java:323)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.commitText(WebViewClassic.java:339)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

However I am not using any webview class directly. However, this problem might be related to AdView, but I don't understand how. My code is the following:

```
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
    //TODO: these lines are created because onPuase of Adview doesn't work

     if ( adView != null ) {
         adView.pause();
         adView.destroy();
         adView = null;

         Log.i(ApplicationData.APP_TAG, TAG + ": OnPause, pausing the Adview");
     }

     super.onPause();

 }
```

The error appears after the Log.i line, I would have expected this error to appear when AdView was called but not after. Is possible that this error is coming from a threaded action? Any idea how to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the example in https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html and the document for [`AdView.destroy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html#destroy()), you should only call `adView.pause()` in `onPause()`, and call `adView.destroy()` later in `onDestroy()`.

The stack dump looks like another thread is accessing the destroyed `AdView` instance.

Comment: Um... for having the exception of webview how will calling this method later on will avoid the issue? I mean... for the kind of error I am getting, why it could be coming from which state of the Activity we are?

Comment: Looks like a `Handler` was still dispatching messages to `WebViewClassic` which is encapsulated inside the destroyed `AdView`.

Comment: Um.... you probably have a point. I will tested in production and if works, questions accepted!!!!

Comment: No issue so far. I think is the solution!

Comment: A new issue is happening... different one, I created a new question. Very strange... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856883/java-nullpointer-exception-from-webview-in-android-webkit-webviewclassic-loaddat